# OpenMP nested for loops (work with Qt)

Tags: c++, qt, parallel-processing, openmp, qpainter

I am wiriting a program (C++) to merge images (QPainter). In sequentially way it's work great, but I must parallelize it with OpenMP. How can I do this? I think that possible problem is memory allocation or nested for loops. It's my first question here, thanks in advance :)

```
int width = (x2-x1)+1;
int height = (y2-y1)+1;

//every image is 256x256
QImage mapa = QImage(256*width, 256*height, QImage::Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied);
QPainter painter(&mapa);

painter.setCompositionMode(QPainter::CompositionMode_SourceOver);

int x=0;
int y=0;


#pragma omp parallel
{
char *kawalek;

#pragma omp parallel for lastprivate(i) firstprivate(j) shared(x1, x2, y1, y2, painter) reduction(+:y, x)
for(i=y1; i<=y2; i++){
    x=0;
    #pragma omp parallel for shared(x1, x2, i, y, painter) reduction(+:x)
    for(j=x1; j<=x2; j++){
        {
        kawalek = (char*) malloc(snprintf(NULL, 0, "pobrane/%d_%d.png", j, i)+1);
        sprintf(kawalek, "pobrane/%d_%d.png", j, i);
        //cout << "czesc: " << kawalek << endl;
        QImage fragment(kawalek);
        painter.drawImage(x, y, fragment);

        //cout << "wspolrzedne czesci x: " << x << "y: " << y << endl;
        }
        x+=256;
    }
    y+=256;
}
}

painter.end();

mapa.save(filename);
```

---

@Riateche, thanks ;)

My next question is why that loop don't speed up...

```
#pragma omp parallel for private(i) shared(ile)
    for(i=0; i<ile; i++){
        results[i].load(sciezki[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't write to variable `mapa` (by painting to it) from several threads in the same time.

If you would use Qt threads, I'd suggest you to pass results of calculation to the main thread using signals and slots. Another way is to create array of results in main thread. Each thread will write only his own result to one cell of the array. After all threads are finished, main thread must read results and paint them.

And consider QImage::load() to load png files. It's simplier than your code.

Comment: >>Another way is to create array of results in main thread.
How that array will looks like?

Comment: For example, `QImage* results = new QImage[count]`.